# Iteration for Ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i've got some problems with VBA in excel. I'm trying to do some equivalent of iteration but in Range type. Ofcourse it doesn't work. Is there any option to omit this or some sort of function that will do what i want?

```
Sub trial()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng_tmp As Range
    Dim rngf As Range

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long

    lastcol = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & Sheets("Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 12).Value <= 5 Then
            Set rng_tmp = Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Data").Cells(i, lastcol))
        End If

        With Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 12)
            If .Value = "11970BR" Or .Value = "13765BR" Or .Value = "14000BR" Or .Value = "14041BR" Or .Value = "14295BR" Or .Value = "14296BR" Or .Value = "14369BR" Or .Value = "14608BR" Or .Value = "14699BR" Then
                Set rng_tmp = Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Data").Cells(i, lastcol)).Select
            End If
        End With

        ***Set rng = Union(rng, rng_tmp)***
    Next i

    rng.Select

End Sub
```

This bold and italic (or piece of code between *) line is an equivalent of i=i+1. Is there a way to apply it to Range type?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is your code doing, or supposed to be doing?

Comment: You don't indicate what's wrong, but I'd venture a guess that there's an issue with using `Set rng_tmp = ...` in two different places prior to your `Set rng = Union()` statement.  Your 2nd `If` statement will overwrite the value of `rng_tmp` set in the 1st `If` statement when both happen to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be several problems, but one I find in particular is that if not one of your if states are applicable, one of the ranges will be empty (or nothing I think excel uses), and you can't union nothing.
For more information about this issue, I would like you to look at this page.
Because there are ways around it.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BetterUnion.aspx

(if you debug your code, you will se that just before taking union, both rng and rng_temp are both nothing if the first cell you check doesn't meet the requirement to join rng_temp, but see the page above for more information). Also a little problem is that your rng will always be empty from the beginning. So you need to check if it is empty/nothing, and if empty, you probably would like to put in the thing you just checked, make rng = rng_temp. With this check below

```
If rng is Nothing Then
```

Hope it helps,
Best Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. Actually I've already solved my problem a couple of hours ago. After reading MS Support i realized, that I can't Union Nothing - excatly as You mentioned. Also i did something like this "BetterUnion" to concatenate some diffrent areas and omit the empty ones. Once more, I'm gratefull, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to loop through each cell in a range, the following works:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10").Cells
    'do something with c here where c is the cell for this iteration
Next
```

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Or `For Each C in Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(lastrow,lastcol)).cells` to make it more applicable to the particular question.